# JavaScript how to retain state on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

So I have this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logIn: false,
      signUp: true,
      signedIn: false
    };
 }
```

and then in my `render()` I have:

```
render(){
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.signedIn
        ?
      <SignedIn />
       :
      <SignUp />
      }
     </div>
    )
 }
```

Basically, if you are signed in by logging in in another function then that is true, if not then render the user the sign up form. That works. However, if I refresh the page the states return to their original state and I have to either sign up or log in again. How can I effectively stay "logged in" or get the browser to remember the state that `this.state.signedIn` is `true` unless I click a log out button etc?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere more persistent as it's in memory, like localStorage

Comment: Where do you change the state from false to true?

Comment: Any state held on the browser is subject to manipulation by the user. How will you stop some user from just adding state to say they are logged on?

Comment: Consider using the server `session`...

Comment: you will need to use something like localStorage, in your case what is happening is , everytime you refresh the browser your app is just starting again like if it the first time you ever used it , try looking for " keep persistent session react app" or something like that , you might find some usefull tips or tutorials

Comment: this is not meant to be secure, right?

Comment: @aw04 I am attempting to create the most secure log in system ever, is this not correct?
only joking. it is just a mini project that I am trying to get working.

Comment: @Richard how do you propose doing "logging in" in React?

Comment: just making sure :) in that case, i second localStorage if you want something simple

Comment: @aw04 ok cheers. is localStorage considered good practice though or does it have the same rep as a global var?

Comment: as with anything it depends on how you use it, but no I would not liken it to a global var... it serves a purpose which is to persist information in the users browser, good for things like remembering preferences/settings

Comment: You could put the validation in `react-router` if you are using that. Then you would validate if the user is logged in against ie local storage and only render the component if the user is logged in. That way you won't have to put state in each and every component.

Comment: Any security relevant state needs to be handled on a server (where you, or someone you trust, has control). A opaque blob could be held on the client but it needs to allow the server check its integrity. Thus login systems use cookies with base 64 encoded values. PS.There nothing in the question indicating you're not serious: I've seen too many such bad practices used on real systems (along with putting untrusted data into database queries with simple string operations).

Comment: @Richard yeh fair enough. I allocate and set a cookie to the equivalent of the useruid I get given to me by firebase when a user signs up. can I check the value of that in componentDidMount and if is 'true' then set state to signed in?